# Office UI fabric react Commandbar 3rd level menu rendering issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-ui-fabric-react

I am using Office UI fabric react commmandbar in Office 365 - SharePoint to display 3 level navigation.It's showing 1st level then click on it user can see 2nd level and onmouseovercof 2nd level,3rd level is populating. I am having the problem when I am adding href to 2nd level then 3rd level is not getting populated and If I remove the href value then 3rd level menu is populating. Is there any way we can overcome this problem or any alternate setting we can apply to commandbar.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I use spfx extension for rendering navigation (starting point was Starter kit). My issue was that when the commandbar becoming less during the browser width minimizing (actually in mobile view), the hovering submenu becoming not clickable.

I fixed it just removing the itemType value (itemType: ContextualMenuItemType) for declaring the "IContextualMenuItem" object for commandbar items.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if ICommandBarProps.items doesn't have unique ids. Ensure you have code as below,

[image]